# How to stream video in android device via .sdp file from android device

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, live-streaming, sdp

I had anapplication to stream `video(without audio)` from `android device(Blaze board)` to PC. For that, I'm using vlc player to view streamed video by using the following command in command line

```
vlc stream.sdp
```

This `.sdp` file would be generated from my application. By using the above command, I can stream from blaze board to PC with the delay of 1 sec.

Now, My problem is that, I have to stream from one blaze board to another blaze board. I have searched a lot. But, Nothing is worked.

I have an idea to write viewer application ( For client ). This application will use sdp file path as url. I refer this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646743/playing-sdp-file-rtsp-stream-from-http-url-in-android). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646743/playing-sdp-file-rtsp-stream-from-http-url-in-android), he had used `"setDataSource(http://localhost/file.sdp)"` . I used like this in my application. But, it also, didn't work.

```
String videoSrc = "rtsp://192.168.13.77:8086/stream.sdp";
```

Here is my code

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        try {
         mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

How to use .sdp file to play streamed video lively?

Whether I am going is correct path or not? If you are having any other way, please suggest me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?